# How can I use a compound condition in a join in Linq?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Let's say I have a `Customer` table which has a `PrimaryContactId` field and a `SecondaryContactId` field. Both of these are foreign keys that reference the `Contact` table. For any given customer, either one or two contacts may be stored. In other words, `PrimaryContactId` can never be `NULL`, but `SecondaryContactId` *can* be `NULL`.

If I drop my `Customer` and `Contact` tables onto the "Linq to SQL Classes" design surface, the class builder will spot the two FK relationships from the `Customer` table to the `Contact` table, and so the generated `Customer` class will have a `Contact` field and a `Contact1` field (which I can rename to `PrimaryContact` and `SecondaryContact` to avoid confusion).

Now suppose that I want to get details of all the contacts for a given set of customers.

*If there was always exactly one contact* then I could write something like:

```
from customer in customers
join contact in contacts on customer.PrimaryContactId equals contact.id
select ...
```

...which would be translated into something like:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Customer
INNER JOIN Contact
ON Customer.FirstSalesPersonId = Contact.id
```

**But**, because I want to join on *both* the contact fields, I want the SQL to look something like:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Customer
INNER JOIN Contact
ON Customer.FirstSalesPersonId = Contact.id OR Customer.SecondSalesPersonId = Contact.id
```

How can I write a Linq expression to do that?

Comment: Isn't an `INNER JOIN` just a different way of writing a `WHERE`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It's rarely correct to use `join` in LINQ to SQL](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/).

Since you want contacts, why not start your selection there? Presuming the association between `Customer` and `Contact` is two-way, you should be able to write something like:

```
IEnumerable<Guid> customerIds = // ...

var q = from contact in Context.Contacts
        where customerIds.Contains(contact.Customer.Id)
        select contact;
```

Comment: You could do it all in one shot too, if you want to. (+1 for link text, fully agree with you there)

Comment: @Craig: this is yet another case where in trying to simplify my question and take it out of my problem domain, I've lost some of the nuances of my situation. I don't think I can come at it the other way, no. But, I take your point about not using join at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use anonymous classes. EG

```
new { A.Foo, B.Bar } equals new { Foo = B.Baz, Bar = C.Ork }
```

Comment: Sorry, I think you've missed the point of the question. That's still an equality test - how can I do condition1 OR condition2?